# I need to fill an icon in bootstrap using javascript

Tags: javascript

i'm just trying to add or remove a class for an icon using bootstrap.

I know my code is bad and i need to improve it, here is why i'm asking your help.
I know it can be reduce by using this, but i don't know how to do with the name of the classes than.

Here is my code :

```js
heart = document.getElementById('heart');
chart = document.getElementById('chart');

heart.addEventListener('click', function(){
    if(heart.classList.contains('bi-heart-fill')){
        heart.classList.add('bi-heart');
        heart.classList.remove('bi-heart-fill');
        heart.style.color='white';
   
    }
    else{
        heart.classList.add('bi-heart-fill');
        heart.classList.remove('bi-heart');
        heart.style.color='#1DB954';
    }
    
})

chart.addEventListener('click', function(){
    if(chart.classList.contains('bi-bar-chart-fill')){
        chart.classList.add('bi-bar-chart');
        chart.classList.remove('bi-bar-chart-fill');
        chart.style.color='white';
   
    }
    else{
        chart.classList.add('bi-bar-chart-fill');
        chart.classList.remove('bi-bar-chart');
        chart.style.color='#1DB954';
    }
    
})
```

Thanks you !

Answer (score 1):

A big part in programming is **D**on't **R**epeat **Y**ourself (DRY).

In your case you can easily create a function which toggles the classes. All you have to do is pass the right parameters.

```js
heart = document.getElementById('heart');
chart = document.getElementById('chart');

function toggleIcon(element, activeClass, inactiveClass) {
  if (element.classList.contains(activeClass)) {
    element.classList.add(inactiveClass);
    element.classList.remove(activeClass);
    element.style.color = 'white';
  } else {
    element.classList.add(activeClass);
    element.classList.remove(inactiveClass);
    element.style.color = '#1DB954';
  }
}

heart.addEventListener('click', function() {
  toggleIcon(heart, 'bi-heart-fill', 'bi-heart');
})

chart.addEventListener('click', function() {
  toggleIcon(chart, 'bi-bar-chart-fill', 'bi-bar-chart');
})
```

Comment: Yeah i know in programming we need to don't repeat ourselves, this is why i'm asking this question --'

Answer (score 1):

A concise way to fix this is using `element.classList.toggle`:

```js
heart.addEventListener('click', function(){
    heart.classList.toggle('bi-heart-fill');
    heart.classList.toggle('bi-heart');

    heart.style.color = heart.classList.contains('bi-heart') ? 'white': '#1DB954'
})

chart.addEventListener('click', function(){
    chart.classList.toggle('bi-bar-chart-fill');
    chart.classList.toggle('bi-bar-chart');

    chart.style.color = chart.classList.contains('bi-bar-chart') ? 'white': '#1DB954'
})
```

If you can add some CSS you can make it even more efficient.

```css
#heart {
   color: white;
}

#heart.black {
     color: #1DB954;
}
```

then

```js
heart.addEventListener('click', function(){
    heart.classList.toggle('bi-heart-fill');
    heart.classList.toggle('bi-heart');
    heart.classList.toggle('black');
})
```

Comment: I like the idea of an extra class for the color, alternatively you can also check if it ends with `-fill` like `[class$="-fill"]`